# How can I add multiple filters to a XSLT for-each statement?

Tags: xslt, xpath, filter, foreach

I have the following XSLT node:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Book[title != 'Moby Dick']">
....
</xsl:for-each>
```

However, I'd like use multiple filters in the for-each.  I've tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<!-- Attempt #1 -->
<xsl:for-each select="Book[title != 'Moby Dick'] or Book[author != 'Rowling'] ">
....
</xsl:for-each>


<!-- Attempt #2 -->
<xsl:for-each select="Book[title != 'Moby Dick' or author != 'Rowling']">
....
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: you should provide XML sample.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and several one-liner solutions. :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> However, I'd like use multiple filters
>   in the for-each

**Your real question is an XPath one**: *Is it possible, and how, to specify more than one condition inside a predicate?*

**Answer**:

Yes, use the standard XPath boolean operators `or` and `and` and the standard XPath function `not()`.

**In this particular case, the XPath in the `select` attribute may be**:

```
Book[title != 'Moby Dick' or author != 'Rowling']
```

I personally would always prefer to write an equivalent expression:

```
Book[not(title = 'Moby Dick') or not(author = 'Rowling')]
```

because the `!=` operator has a non-intuitive behavior when one of its operands is a node-set.

**But I am guessing that what you probably wanted was to `and` the two comparissons -- not to `or` them**.

Comment: If you get a chance, would you mind explaining or linking to an explanation about the != operator's non-intuitive behavior? Thanks!

Comment: @Neil Whitaker: if at least one of the operands of the `!=` operator is a node-set (or a node-set or a sequence in XPath 2.0), then it is possible that both `$arg1 = $arg2` and `$arg1 != $arg2` are true at the same time. Just read the definition of the `!=` operator. This is avoided if you use `not($arg1 = $arg2)`

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, I forgot to refresh my data.  Attempt #2 works perfectly fine.  Hopefully this example helps someone else.

```
<!-- Attempt #2 -->
<xsl:for-each select="Book[title != 'Moby Dick' or author != 'Rowling']">
....
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: @Dimitre - if Rowling had written a book called Moby Dick, the predicate would surely be false for that book?

Comment: @Michael: Of course you are right. I probably was thinking that the *same* element was participating in two `!=` comparisons with different values, which comparisons were then or-ed. Must have been quite tired last night... Anyway, I removed a similar statement from my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple predicates, the simplest way is just to use multiple predicates. I'm guessing you really want an "and" rather than an "or":

```
<xsl:for-each select="Book[title != 'Moby Dick'][author != 'Rowling'] ">
....
</xsl:for-each>
```

Generally the != operator is best avoided, because it has unexpected effects when the author is absent or when there are multiple authors. It's better to write:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Book[not(title = 'Moby Dick')][not(author = 'Rowling')] ">
....
</xsl:for-each>
```